# Indefinite size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to make a simple program that counts the number of vowels and consonants the user's name has. The size of the array is dependent on how many letters does the user's name has. I'm using queue to display the letters. When ever I run the program, the .Exe file crashes. So I tried to change the array size to a number instead of a variable and it worked. The problem is in using a variable for the size of the array, I think. Is there anyway to fix it? So that I can still use a variable for the size of my array. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    char bin[i];
    queue<char> name;
    int v = 0, c = 0;

    cout << "how many letters does your name have?:";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Enter the letters of your name one by one:\n";

    do {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            cout << " ";
            cin >> bin[k];
            name.push(bin[k]);

            if (bin[k] == 'a' || bin[k] == 'A') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'e' || bin[k] == 'E') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'i' || bin[k] == 'I') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'o' || bin[k] == 'O') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'u' || bin[k] == 'U') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'b' || bin[k] == 'B') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'c' || bin[k] == 'C') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'i' || bin[k] == 'D') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'f' || bin[k] == 'F') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'g' || bin[k] == 'G') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'h' || bin[k] == 'H') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'j' || bin[k] == 'J') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'k' || bin[k] == 'K') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'l' || bin[k] == 'L') {
                v++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'm' || bin[k] == 'M') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'n' || bin[k] == 'N') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'P' || bin[k] == 'p') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'q' || bin[k] == 'Q') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'r' || bin[k] == 'R') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 's' || bin[k] == 'S') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 't' || bin[k] == 'T') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'v' || bin[k] == 'V') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'w' || bin[k] == 'W') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'x' || bin[k] == 'X') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'y' || bin[k] == 'Y') {
                c++;
            }
            if (bin[k] == 'z' || bin[k] == 'Z') {
                c++;
            }
        }
    } while (bin[100] != '1');

    cout << "\n\nYour name is:\n";
    for (queue<char> run = name; !run.empty(); run.pop()) {
        cout << " " << run.front() << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nVowels= " << v;
    cout << "\nConsonants= " << c << "\n";

    cout << "\n\n\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please disregard the do while function

Comment: ISO C++ does not contain variable length arrays.

Comment: Some C++ compilers do support C's VLAs as an extension.   Even in C (or C++ compilers which support that extention) that usage of variable length arrays is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  `int i;` creates an uninitialized `int` named `i`.  Then you use the uninitialized garbage variable in `char bin[i];`.  So now we have an array with undefined size.

At this point we can't go any further.  Once undefined behavior is invoked we can no longer reason how the code should work.  If you need an array and you are not going to know what the size is until run time then you should use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Comment: A bit of nitpicking, but doesn't invoking UB make the whole program impossible to reason about? Not just from invoking and beyond. The compiler might do something funny etc.

Comment: Why vector or queue?  std::string can able to solve his problem

Comment: Agree with NathanOliver, your compiler must have warning you about this, if not turn up the warning and error checking levels.

Comment: @Ilja AFAIK you can reason about a program until the point you reach undefined behavior.  Once you encounter it then all bets are off.

Comment: @NathanOliver the compiler might for example decide to skip a whole block if it contains UB or just about anything actually, I think. That for example would mean that the block could not be reasoned about "until the point" of UB. Not 100% sure though, since I should reread what the standard says about UB.

Comment: @Ilja I changed *can no longer reason how the rest of the code should work* to *can no longer reason how the code should work*.  That should cover it all.

Comment: It really worked Nathan. I just initialized `int i` to zero and that fixed it.

Comment: llja - Nathan is correct about ability to reason about a program before code with undefined behaviour is reached.   Once undefined behaviour occurs, it is not generally possible to reason about behaviour of the program.    But the behaviour of any code executed before an instance of undefined behaviour can be reasoned about.

Comment: You're getting lucky, Schneizel.  The behaviour of that is undefined, but sometimes an instance of undefined behaviour can appear to work correctly.    Specify a positive value that is large enough to hold any data you allow (and take steps to permit more data being read).